# obtener los valores del formulario por ajax y pasarlo a una consulta

Tags: php, jquery, html5, ajax, highcharts

Tengo un formulario para filtrar los datos para generar gráficos de los datos de las encuestas

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-rc.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <br /><br />

      
        <form id="formulario" class="form-inline" method="post" style="margin-left: 5%;">


          <div class="form-group">
            <label >Seleccione Asignatura:</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="cursos" id="autocomplete">
          </div>


           <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="cod_curso" name="cod_curso" style="display:none;">
           </div>

  
           <div id="secciones" class="form-group"></div>
      
 
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="sel1">Seleccione año:</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="anio" id="anio" placeholder="" required>
                  <option value=2015>2015
                  <option value=2016>2016 
                  <option value=2017>2017 
                  <option value=2018>2018 
                  <option value=2019>2019 
               </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="sel1">Seleccione semestre:</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="semestre" id="semestre" placeholder="" required>
                  <option value=Primer>Primer 
                  <option value=Segundo>Segundo
               </select>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group text-center" style="margin-left: 50px;">
                <button id="myButton" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Generar</button>
            </div>

        </form>
        
        <div id="grafico"></div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

```js
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-rc.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
    
$(document).on('ready',function(){       
    $('#myButton').click(function(){
            var url = "grafico_prueba.php";
            $.ajax({                        
            type: "POST",                 
            url: url,                     
            data: $("#formulario").serialize(), 
            success: function(data)
            {
             $('#grafico').html(data);               
           }
       });
    });
});
    

   </script>
    <script>
        var Cursos = [
            <?php
                $query2 = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT DISTINCT cod_ramo FROM cursos");
                $cantidad_cursos = mysqli_num_rows($query2);
    $i = 1; 
            
                while ($valores2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)) {
                    echo  "'" . $valores2['cod_ramo'] . "'";
                    if($i < $cantidad_cursos) {
                        echo ", "; 
                        $i++;
                    }
                }
            ?>
        ]


        $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
            source: Cursos,
            select: function(event, ui) {

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "secciones.php",
                        method: "GET",
                        data: {
                            cod_ramo: ui.item.value
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            $('#secciones').html(data);
                        }

                });
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Este formulario tiene un ajax para anidar asignatura con las secciones y otro para encontrar la clave única de ese curso(cod_curso) que esta oculta.

y luego eso valores de los input necesito pasarlo a un gráfico highchart

grafico_prueba.php

```js
<script>    
    
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Grafico'
    },
    xAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Pregunta'
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [   
        <?php 
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM preguntas";
  $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
  while ($registros = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
        ?>
            '<?php echo $registros["nombre"] ?>',
        <?php
  }
  ?>]
        
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Porcentajes'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.percentage:.0f}%)<br/>',
        shared: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'percent'
        }
    },
    series: [{
       name: 'no aplica',
        data:  <?php 
    $sql = "FROM preguntas p 
                        
                        LEFT JOIN tipo_respuesta tr on p.id_pregunta = tr.id_pregunta 
                        
                        LEFT JOIN respuesta r on tr.id_tipo = r.id_tipo

                        LEFT JOIN form_alumnos f on r.id_form_alumno_fk = f.id_form_alumno 
                        
   WHERE (f.cod_curso_alumno = '$cod_curso' AND f.anio = '$anio' AND f.semestre = '$semestre' or cod_curso_alumno IS NULL or anio IS NULL or semestre IS NULL)  and tr.tipo = '1'
                        
                        GROUP BY p.id_pregunta, tr.tipo";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
    ?>
                [<?php while ($registros = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?><?php echo $registros["cantidad_respuestas"] ?>, 
                 <?php }?>]
    }, {
        name: 'muy en desacuerdo',
        data:  <?php 
    $sql = "FROM preguntas p 
                        
                        LEFT JOIN tipo_respuesta tr on p.id_pregunta = tr.id_pregunta 
                        
                        LEFT JOIN respuesta r on tr.id_tipo = r.id_tipo

                        LEFT JOIN form_alumnos f on r.id_form_alumno_fk = f.id_form_alumno 
                        
   WHERE (f.cod_curso_alumno = '$cod_curso' AND f.anio = '$anio' AND f.semestre = '$semestre' or cod_curso_alumno IS NULL or anio IS NULL or semestre IS NULL)  and tr.tipo = '2'
                        
                        GROUP BY p.id_pregunta, tr.tipo";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
    ?>
                [<?php while ($registros = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?><?php echo $registros["cantidad_respuestas"] ?>, 
                 <?php }?>]
    }, {
        name: 'en desacuerdo',
        data:  <?php 
    $sql = "FROM preguntas p 
                        
                        LEFT JOIN tipo_respuesta tr on p.id_pregunta = tr.id_pregunta 
                        
                        LEFT JOIN respuesta r on tr.id_tipo = r.id_tipo

                        LEFT JOIN form_alumnos f on r.id_form_alumno_fk = f.id_form_alumno 
                        
   WHERE (f.cod_curso_alumno = '$cod_curso' AND f.anio = '$anio' AND f.semestre = '$semestre' or cod_curso_alumno IS NULL or anio IS NULL or semestre IS NULL)  and tr.tipo = '3'
                        
                        GROUP BY p.id_pregunta, tr.tipo";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
    ?>
                [<?php while ($registros = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?><?php echo $registros["cantidad_respuestas"] ?>, 
                 <?php }?>]
    }, {
        name: 'en acuerdo',
        data:  <?php 
    $sql = "FROM preguntas p 
                        
                        LEFT JOIN tipo_respuesta tr on p.id_pregunta = tr.id_pregunta 
                        
                        LEFT JOIN respuesta r on tr.id_tipo = r.id_tipo

                        LEFT JOIN form_alumnos f on r.id_form_alumno_fk = f.id_form_alumno 
                        
   WHERE (f.cod_curso_alumno = '$cod_curso' AND f.anio = '$anio' AND f.semestre = '$semestre' or cod_curso_alumno IS NULL or anio IS NULL or semestre IS NULL)  and tr.tipo = '4'
                        
                        GROUP BY p.id_pregunta, tr.tipo";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
    ?>
                [<?php while ($registros = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?><?php echo $registros["cantidad_respuestas"] ?>, 
                 <?php }?>]
    }, {
        name: 'muy de acuerdo',
        data:  <?php 
    $sql = "FROM preguntas p 
                        
                        LEFT JOIN tipo_respuesta tr on p.id_pregunta = tr.id_pregunta 
                        
                        LEFT JOIN respuesta r on tr.id_tipo = r.id_tipo

                        LEFT JOIN form_alumnos f on r.id_form_alumno_fk = f.id_form_alumno 
                        
   WHERE (f.cod_curso_alumno = '$cod_curso' AND f.anio = '$anio' AND f.semestre = '$semestre' or cod_curso_alumno IS NULL or anio IS NULL or semestre IS NULL)  and tr.tipo = '5'
                        
                        GROUP BY p.id_pregunta, tr.tipo";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
    ?>
                [<?php while ($registros = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?><?php echo $registros["cantidad_respuestas"] ?>, 
                 <?php }?>]
    }]
});


</script>
```

```html
<?php
require_once('../conexion.php');
mysqli_query($mysqli,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$cod_curso = $_POST['cod_curso'];
$anio  = $_POST['anio'];
$semestre  = $_POST['semestre'];




?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="../Highcharts-6.0.2/code/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="../Highcharts-6.0.2/code/themes/grid-light.js"></script>
    
    
    <script src="../Highcharts-6.0.2/code/modules/exporting.js"></script>
       <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0">
   
   <div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 600px; margin: 0"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

mi problema al momento de pasar la variable al php, no entiendo muy bien como aplicarlo en el gráfico y que cada vez que se filtra por un curso cambie el dato del gráfico.

Cualquier orientación o ayuda sera bien recibida.

Comment: Lo has podido solucionar? si tiene inconvenientes me escribes por aquí @cladia24

Comment: si solucione lo de gráfico gracias, ahora me falta arreglar mi consulta por que aun no me arroja todos los datos que necesito, tendré que pensar bien la consulta el fin de semana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejare este código que utilice en algún momento, presentaba el mismo inconveniente, es muy parecido al tuyo, el código esta probado y funciona correctamente, adáptalo a tus necesidades, y me cuentas.

**HTML - Selects para filtrar**

```
<tr>  
    <td width="150" align="right"><font face="arial"><b>AÑO</b></font></td>
    <td>
      <select name="ANO_ACTA" id="ANO_ACTA" autofocus="autofocus">
      <option>Seleccione...</option>
      <option value="2017">2017</option>
      <option value="2018">2018</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td width="150" align="right"><font face="arial"><b>MES</b></font></td>
    <td>
      <select name="MES_ACTA" id="MES_ACTA">
        <option>Seleccione...</option>
        <option value="ENERO">ENERO</option>
        <option value="FEBRERO">FEBRERO</option>
        <option value="MARZO">MARZO</option>
        <option value="ABRIL">ABRIL</option>
        <option value="MAYO">MAYO</option>
        <option value="JUNIO">JUNIO</option>
        <option value="JULIO">JULIO</option>
        <option value="AGOSTO">AGOSTO</option>
        <option value="SEPTIEMBRE">SEPTIEMBRE</option>
        <option value="OCTUBRE">OCTUBRE</option>
        <option value="NOVIEMBRE">NOVIEMBRE</option>
        <option value="DICIEMBRE">DICIEMBRE</option>
      </select>
    </td>   
  </tr>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
jQuery(function ($) {

  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {

        //Nombre del div contenedor
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'spline'
    },

    title: {
      text: '<b></b>Seleccione y Año y Mes...</b>'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Informe Rollout Mensual'
    },

    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Valores en Millones'
      }
    },

    xAxis: {
      //Categorías en duro o estaticas
      categories: ['DIA 1','DIA 2','DIA 3','DIA 4','DIA 5','DIA 6','DIA 7','DIA 8','DIA 9','DIA 10','DIA 11','DIA 12','DIA 13','DIA 14','DIA 15','DIA 16','DIA 17','DIA 18','DIA 19','DIA 20','DIA 21','DIA 22','DIA 23','DIA 24','DIA 25','DIA 26','DIA 27','DIA 28', 'DIA 29', 'DIA 30', 'DIA 31']
    },

    //Series o numero de lineas estadísticas 
    series: [

    {
      name : "CUNDINAMARCA",
      data: [],
      marker: {
      lineWidth: 5,
      lineColor: ''

      }

    },

    {
      name : "VALLE",
      data: [],
      marker: {
      lineWidth: 5,
      lineColor: ''
      }

    },

    {
      name : "CAUCA",
      data: [],
      marker: {
      lineWidth: 5,
      lineColor: '',
      fillColor: ''
      }

    },

    {
      name : "META",
      data: [],
      marker: {
      lineWidth: 5,
      lineColor: '',
      fillColor: ''
      }
    }]
  });

    //Funcion que al cambiar el `select` llama los datos
    $( "#MES_ACTA" ).change(function() {
    //validamos las fechass
    var ANO_ACTA = $('#ANO_ACTA').val();
    var MES_ACTA = $('#MES_ACTA').val();


    chart.setTitle({text: "<b></b>Facturación del Mes de <b>" + $("#MES_ACTA option:selected").val() + "</b>"});
    chart.setTitle(null, {text: "<b></b>Informe Rollout Mensual Año: <b>" + $("#ANO_ACTA option:selected").val() + "</b>"});
    //chart.setTitle: permite cambiar el dinamicamente el titulo y el subtitulo('null,') declarando el elemento seleccionado(option:selected) 
    $.ajax({
      url: "procesar.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: { ANO_ACTA: ANO_ACTA, MES_ACTA: MES_ACTA},
      dataType: "json"
    })

    .done(function(data) {
      //Impleméntalo para que ver que te arroja en la consola, o visualizar si tiene un erro
      console.log(ANO_ACTA);
      console.log(MES_ACTA);
      console.log(data);

      chart.series[0].setData(data[0]); 
      chart.series[1].setData(data[1]);
      chart.series[2].setData(data[2]);  
      chart.series[3].setData(data[3]);  
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<table width="1300" border="1" bordercolor="red" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td><div id="container"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php require_once'../Connections/conexion.php';

$MES_ACTA = $_POST['MES_ACTA']; 
$ANO_ACTA = $_POST['ANO_ACTA'];

$resultado = [];
$resultado2 = [];
$resultado3 = [];
$resultado4 = [];

for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++) { 
    $query= "SELECT SUM(VALOR) as total_DIA_1_CUNDINAMARCA FROM rollout_2017 WHERE ANO_ACTA = '$ANO_ACTA' AND MES_ACTA = '$MES_ACTA' AND DIA= '$i' AND DEPARTAMENTO = 'CUNDINAMARCA' AND TIPO_MAT = 'MO'"; 
    $result =  mysql_query($query, $conexion); 
    $valor = mysql_result($result, 0); 
    $resultado[] = round($valor, 1); 
}

for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++) { 
    $query2= "SELECT SUM(VALOR) as total_DIA_1_VALLE_DEL_CAUCA FROM rollout_2017 WHERE ANO_ACTA = '$ANO_ACTA' AND MES_ACTA = '$MES_ACTA' AND DIA = '$i' AND DEPARTAMENTO = 'VALLE DEL CAUCA' AND TIPO_MAT = 'MO'"; 
    $result2 =  mysql_query($query2, $conexion); 
    $valor2 = mysql_result($result2, 0); 
    $resultado2[] = round($valor2, 1); 
}

for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++) { 
$query3= "SELECT SUM(VALOR) as total_DIA_1_CAUCA FROM rollout_2017 WHERE ANO_ACTA = '$ANO_ACTA' AND MES_ACTA = '$MES_ACTA' AND DIA = '$i' AND DEPARTAMENTO = 'CAUCA' AND TIPO_MAT = 'MO'"; 
    $result3 =  mysql_query($query3, $conexion); 
    $valor3 = mysql_result($result3, 0); 
    $resultado3[] = round($valor3, 1); 
}

for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++) { 
    $query4= "SELECT SUM(VALOR) as total_DIA_1_META FROM rollout_2017 WHERE ANO_ACTA = '$ANO_ACTA' AND MES_ACTA ='$MES_ACTA' AND DIA = '$i' AND DEPARTAMENTO = 'META' AND TIPO_MAT = 'MO'"; 
    $result4 =  mysql_query($query4, $conexion); 
    $valor4 = mysql_result($result4, 0); 
    $resultado4[] = round($valor4, 1); 

}
//Si es mas de una "linea" o consulta, tienes que pasar los datos como array
echo json_encode([$resultado, $resultado2, $resultado3, $resultado4]);

?>
```

Comment: muchas gracias, me sirvió mucho para guiarme y entender lo que tenia que hacer

Comment: Dale, me alegra que te sriviera